# How I can call method in fragment from activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have main activity and I want to call method inside fragment I use getSupportFragmentManager for get fragment but always return null to me can you help me please

mainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemPressListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
   public void A()
   {
       FragmentManager fragManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
      MainFragment fragment= (MainFragment)fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mainfragment);///always Null
       fragment.B();
   }.
}
```

main_fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainfragment"
    tools:context=".mainFragment">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_movie"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"></GridView>
</FrameLayout>
```

MainFragmet:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
 public void B() {
///do some thing
}
}
```

Comment: Is a Fragment actually loaded into `R.id.mainfragment`? There is no code in your `MainActivity` that suggests you do.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to get an instance from the fragment inside the main activity

```
MainFragment fragment=new MainFragment();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code in your question that suggests you ever instantiate a `Fragment` and load it into `R.id.mainfragment`. In addition, your `main_fragment.xml` file contains an `GridView` with `match_parent` parameters. This is pointless if you intend to load a fragment into `R.id.mainfragment`, as your `GridView` will only obscure it.

With that in mind, I would make the following corrections to your code.

1. Remove your `GridView` from your `layout` file:

   ```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:id="@+id/mainfragment"
       tools:context=".mainFragment" />
   ```
2. Add something like the following to your `onCreate()` in `MainActivity`:

   ```
   if(getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mainfragment) == null) {
       getSupportFragmentManager()
           .beginTransaction
           .add(R.id.mainfragment, new MainFragment())
           .commit();
   }

   //...This can be in onCreate(), or inside a method, to access MainFragment's methods
   MainFragment frag = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainfragment);
   if (frag != null) frag.callYourMethodHere();
   ```

Comment: Where I can put gridView  If i delete from  main_fragment

Comment: @mohammadtofi That depends on its purpose, but my immediate thought is that it should be part of your Fragment's layout, if you want it to occupy the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use findFragmentById... You must write like this:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainfragment"
    class="com.oldfeel.base.BaseFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: findFragmentById() can also be used with dynamic fragments, not just static fragments.

Answer (score 0):

First you haven't instantiate your fragment in the main activity try the code below:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
            // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment, "myAwesonFragment").commit();
        }
    }
```

then if your method A do the following

```
public void A()
   {
       BrowseFragment fragment = (BrowseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myAwesonFragment");
        //Check if the Bottom Sheet is Expanded
        fragment.B();
   }
```

And that's it this time it won't be null. I personally always use findFragmentByTag when I want to locate a fragment.

PD: we used getSupportFragmentManager() because you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment if your using android.app.Fragment use getFragmentManager()